# upgrade cassandra from 2.1.14 to 3.0.6, do I have to run nodetool upgradesstables?

Tags: cassandra

I have a cassandra cluster with version 2.1.14, and plan to upgrade it to 3.0.6.
In the upgrade guide, it says that:

> Cassandra 3.0.x restrictions
>
> Upgrade from Cassandra 2.1 versions later or equal to 2.1.9 directly to Cassandra 3.0.x.

So, should I have to run `nodetool upgradesstables` when upgrade 2.1.14 to 3.0.6?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should run the `upgradesstables` . SStables format have changed between 2.1.x and 3.x. General [upgrade procedures](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-upgrade/upgrade/cassandra/upgradeCassandraDetails.html) explicitly mentions it should be run during major versions upgrade.